# Simulate largest value of Math.random()

Tags: java, random

I am mocking the static `random()` method of the `Math` class in Java to better test a method that relies on generating random numbers. The code I am using is as follows:

```
@Mock
public double random() {
    return 1.0 - Double.MIN_VALUE;
}
```

This is my attempt at reaching a value as close to 1.0 as possible without being equal. (e.g. 0.999999999999...)

However, when I invoke the mocked `Math.random()` method I always get 1.0 as the value. It's almost as if subtracting the `Double.MIN_VALUE` does not affect the 1.0 at all.

Why does `1.0 - Double.MIN_VALUE` result in 1.0 and how can I simulate the largest possible value of `Math.random()`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288334/increase-a-double-to-the-next-closest-value

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155378/how-to-alter-a-float-by-its-smallest-increment-or-close-to-it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Math.random() Max Value (double just less than 1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736885/java-math-random-max-value-double-just-less-than-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`double` has limit precision. The closest number to `1.0 - Double.MIN_VALUE` that can be represented as double is 1.0. That's why you get `1.0`.

A double has 1 bit for sign, 11 bits for exponent and 52 bits for fraction. ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format))

The double value represented by 64 bits is `(-1)^sign+1.b51b50...b0 x 2^(e-1023)`

The closest to 1.0 you can get is when all the fraction bits are 1 and the exponent is `e-1023==-1`.
That value is `0.1111..111` (53 ones) in binary.

To get that value in decimal :

```
double d = 0.0;
double exp =1.0;
for (int i=1;i<=53;i++) {
  exp=exp*2.0;
  d+=1.0/exp;
}
System.out.println (d);
System.out.println ("d==1.0? " + (d==1.0));
```

It prints

```
0.9999999999999999
d==1.0? false
```

If you add another iteration to the loop (i.e. `i<=54)` you get:

```
1.0
d==1.0? true
```

Comment: Then what is the largest possible value returned by `Math.random()`?

Answer (score 1):

According to IEEE 754
double has 15.95 Decimal digits

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

so if you try `double a = 1e0 - 1e-16 //or less`  you will have a == 1e0

Comment: Sounds good. Using `1.0 - 1e-15` generates a value less than 1.0

Answer (score 1):

`double` is not precise enough to show you the number generated when doing `1.0 - Double.MIN_VALUE`. This is pointed out [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) when discussing Java primitive types. You may find this answer interesting as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15736977/4381697